# Bash Permission Denied when try to execute a jar files dependecies (SUSE Linux)

Tags: java, linux, bash

I've a JAR file with dependencies, when I execute it in Suse Console, an error appears.

This is the command:

```
java -cp ./arba-api-host-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;./log4j-1.2.17.jar;./json-20180130.jar;./junit-4.12.jar  ar.gov.aba.callnatural.LlamadaNatural "S" "SECALL" " " " " " " " " " "
```

And this is the error:

```
-bash: ./log4j-1.2.17.jar: Permission denied
-bash: ./json-20180130.jar: Permission denied
-bash: ./junit-4.12.jar: Permission denied
```

Those JARs are the dependencies.

Comment: On Linux you need to use `:` as the separator in your classpath. `;` is already used to separate commands in the shell.

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much. Beginner errors :p.

Comment: The other answer says NOT to use `:` as the separator on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux don't use `:` as the separator in your classpath. the `;` is used to separate this.

Comment: ...to separate what? Looks like your answer was truncated. Can you [edit] it?

Comment: The comment in the question says to use `:` as the separator on Linux?